# Access HTML dataset

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, html-dataset

I am trying to access a dataset in my HTML. Normally if it was:

```
<td data-mmyyyy="23"></td>
```

You could access it with

```
tdObj.dataset.mmyyyy
```

but for some reason that is not working for me here.

```
var mmyyyy = tds[i].dataset.mmyyyy.split('/');
```

I stopped it on the debugger and output the following from the console:

```
tds // (ME)
  [(enumerated td nodes)] // (CONSOLE)
tds[i] // (ME)
  <td> // (CONSOLE)
    <a href="#" data-mmyyyy="3/2015">22</a>
  </td>
tds[i].dataset // (ME)
  DOMStringMap {}  // (CONSOLE)
tds[i].dataset.mmyyyy // (ME)
  undefined  // (CONSOLE)
```

Can anyone tell me how to approach this differently to access that data attribute? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look better at the console, you'll see that it logs this:

```html
<td>
    <a href="#" data-mmyyyy="3/2015">22</a>
</td>
```

So, according to the data logged by the console, the `dataset` you're trying to access is not on your `<td>` element, but on its `<a>` child.

To access it you can do this:

```
tds[i].children[0].dataset.mmyyyy
```

Or, better, with `querySelector`:

```
tds[i].querySelector("a").dataset.mmyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! The dataset is on the  tag within the  tag. So the correct accessor will be

```
tds[i].children[0].dataset.mmyyyy
```